# Codeigniter not uploading image

Tags: php, codeigniter

### Problem

I have form for registring students. Now I am trying to insert data with uploading image however to database comes only file name. Uploads file is empty! My view form input type is 'file'.

### Controller

```
$config['upload_path'] = APPPATH.'uploads';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $this->upload->do_upload('image');
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    if($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        $data = array(
            'student_name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
            'student_surname'=>$this->input->post('surname'),
            'student_middlename'=>$this->input->post('middlename'),
            'student_birth'=>$this->input->post('date'),
            'student_add_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
            'student_gender'=>$this->input->post('gender'),
            'student_addres'=>$this->input->post('address'),
            'student_mobile'=>$this->input->post('phone'),
            'student_email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
            'student_image'=>$this->upload->do_upload('image')

        );

        $this->member->add_student($data);
        redirect('members/student_list');               
    }
```

Comment: Where your uploads folder is located?

Comment: Make sure the 'uploads' folder has write permission.

Comment: codeigniter in core file

Comment: Try placing uploads folder out side of application folder then `$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH .  'uploads';` When uploading files it is not a post();

Comment: did you check <form enctype="multipart/formdata"> ?

Comment: yes, after your comment I added however it comes 0 result

Answer (score 0):

You can do just this,

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide below statement instead of  $config['upload_path'] = APPPATH .'uploads';

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
```

And also ensure that your uploads folder created in the outside of application folder

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
if($this->form_validation->run())
{
      //configure and load upload library
        $config['upload_path'] =getcwd().'/uploads';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '10000';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

   //if can't upload image exit the function 
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('image')) {
        $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
        //use var_dump only developing environment
        var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
       // exit();
    }

    $data = array(
        'student_name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
        'student_surname'=>$this->input->post('surname'),
        'student_middlename'=>$this->input->post('middlename'),
        'student_birth'=>$this->input->post('date'),
        'student_add_date' => date('Y-m-d'),
        'student_gender'=>$this->input->post('gender'),
        'student_addres'=>$this->input->post('address'),
        'student_mobile'=>$this->input->post('phone'),
        'student_email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
        // 'student_image'=>$this->upload->do_upload('image'),

    );



    $this->member->add_student($data);
    redirect('members/student_list');               
}
```

Comment: now that is not adding, after submitting just refreshing the page

Comment: print the uploading error like this `echo  $this->upload->display_errors();`

Comment: put `var_dump($data)` outside if condition

Answer (score 0):

change/edit your .htaccess file to :

```
              <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                 RewriteEngine On
                 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
                  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
                  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
              </IfModule>
```

then in your controller set:

```
                  $upload_dir = 'upload_folder';
                  $config['upload_path'] =  $upload_dir ;
                  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
```